# What are the limitations of ksoap2 library?

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I want to send data to the server using asp web service from my Android application. For this I'm using ksoap2 library. The data I'm sending is in the form of an `Content` object. The structure of Content class is:

```
class Content{
   int contentId;
   string xmlContent;
}
```

The xmlContent is big, 1k to 100k lines. My question is, using ksoap2 library is recommended for this type of operations? Is there any limitations of ksoap2 library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also used the Ksop in my program.But i never faced such difficulty it can't be overcome. I have one suggestion to you to use JSON rather than xmlContent. There is a inbuilt java serialization in asp. Just use that and you will get a json response inside you android.Just parse the json using ksop. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) you will get a good idea about ksop.